# Convert time duration a to decimal figure

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am in needs of a formula for converting a duration of a work, already expressed in hour and seconds to a decimal representation. I mean the clock is divided in four parts, of 25 units each.

For example, these are the entries and the desired results:

8h 00m = 8,00
8h 15m = 8,25
8h 30m = 6,50
8h 45m = 8,75

The recording system doesn't allow entries outside a quarter, like 8h 10m, 6h 35m etc... everything is constrained within the corresponding quarter, so the formula could take this into account.

I am not a math guru, so any correction to this question regarding tags, title and syntax is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time in decimal is equal to hours + minutes / 60.

So $$8 \textrm{hr}, 45 \textrm{min} = 8+\frac{45}{60} = 8.75 \textrm{hr}$$

Comment: I am too deep into programming language that I forgot the basis. I could easily parse the string and retrieve the ',45' part, or use one of the many datetime functions available in all the modern programming language, but is there an easy way to 'mathematically' retrieve the value 45.

Comment: Mathematically, retrieving the "45" part is just saying "this is the minutes part". The specific implementation is not a mathematical question, but a programming question. There are many ways to write time. Is it "8:45" or "8.45" or "8,45" or "8hr, 45min" or "8 and 45" or "8 hr, 45 min" or.... you get the picture.